# A simple derivative

Tags: condensed-matter, differentiation, greens-functions

I'm working through a simple derivative in the second edition of Altland and Simons, and I keep getting the wrong answer when I take a derivative.

Given equation 5.22:
$$G_p \equiv \frac{1}{- i \omega_n + \frac{p^2}{2m} - \mu}$$

the text on page 219 claims $\partial_\mu G_p = - (G_p)^2$, but I'm unable to reproduce this result:

$$\partial_\mu G_p = - \frac{1 \times (-1)}{(- i \omega_n + \frac{p^2}{2m} - \mu)^2} = \frac{1}{(- i \omega_n + \frac{p^2}{2m} - \mu)^2} = (G_p)^2,$$

without the minus sign.

This minus sign is carried into subsequent calculations involving $\partial_\mu G_p$, such as $N^{(1)}, N_{\text{RPA}} \; $ on page 219, so I am less inclined to think it is a typo and more that I am missing something.

Comment: I don't have the book so I don't have the context. Purely from the math, if you discount a typo in the result, you might instead look at whether there is a typo in the original expression for $G_p$, namely that the last term of the denominator should be $+\mu$ instead of $-\mu$. Again, I'm just looking at the expression mathematically looking for possible mistakes that would lead to consistency with what you stated - No statement about the physics here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I evaluated the partial derivative, both by hand and in Mathematica. I got the same result as you got. I don't possess any knowledge regarding condensed matter but I can assure you that your calculations are correct.